# Android error 'merged failed' but not the common error everywhere

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am having the following error while trying to run my Android project.

If I use `tools:replace="allowBackup,supportsRtl"` then the scenerio formed is as follows in the screenshots:-

[Here is the error details screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eje2.png)

[Here is my manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXdc8.png)

[Here is the error showing in the merged manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOGh8.png)

But if I use tools:replace="android:value" there then the following error appears in the merged manifest file:-

[The above is the error in merged manifest file and the bottom is the general error shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNufF.png)

Here are my Gradle files:-

Here is the app level Gradle file:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.todolist"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
dataBinding.enabled = true
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
//add Recycler view dependencies; must match SDK version
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
//FAB dependencies
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
//Testing
// Instrumentation dependencies use androidTestCompile
// (as opposed to testCompile for local unit tests run in the JVM)
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
}
```

Here is the project level Gradle file:-

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Android Studio version is 3.1.2. I have tried cleaning & rebuilding the project many times. I have also tried invalidating caches but nothing helped. I do not think that this error can be rectified by doing the tasks mentioned in the previous two lines.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make your `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, and `targetSdkVersion` to use the same version. Use version 27. So, change your **app** build.gradle to:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.todolist"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

   // ... redacted
```

Then you need to use the support library version 27 for your dependencies. So, change your support libraries in dependencies block to:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    //add Recycler view dependencies; must match SDK version
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    //FAB dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    //Testing
    // Instrumentation dependencies use androidTestCompile
    // (as opposed to testCompile for local unit tests run in the JVM)
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

}
```

Then remove the following line in your dependencies block:

```
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

because it is not your dependency but it should be placed to **root** `build.gradle` as a classpath.

Here your root build.gradle should be:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
    belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I tried all that you suggested but still getting the merger failed error like this.

Comment: Error: tools:replace specified at line:6 for attribute android:value, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 5

Comment: Solved !!! I just used the above edits suggested by you and removed the tools:replace="android:value" line from my manifest and it worked like magic. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Great! Glad it help you !